# What happens when async code attempts to resume on a thread that is already executing?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I feel that the answer to this is due to me having an incorrect concept of how threads work, but here goes.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.TestMethodAsync();   // No await, i.e. fire and forget

  // ** Some code here to perform long running calculation (1) **
}

private async Task TestMethodAsync()
{
  // Some synchronous stuff

  await Task.Delay(1000);

  // ** Some code here to perform long running calculation (2) **
}
```

First of all, I would not "fire and forget" an asynchronous method like this (I would use Task.Run) but I've come across code that does, and I'm trying to understand what the effect is.

In a WinForms application, which uses a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, my understanding of async and await tells me that when I click button1, the method will start synchronously on the UI thread. It will call `TestMethodAsync` and run synchronously until it reaches the await. It will then capture the context, start the `Task.Delay` task, and yield control to the caller. Since we are not awaiting this call, `button1_Click` will continue on the UI thread and start performing calculation (1).

At some point, `Task.Delay(1000)` will complete. A continuation will then run the remainder of the `TestMethodAsync` method using the captured context, which in this case means that the continuation will be run on the  UI thread. This will now start performing calculation (2).

We now have two separate sections of code wanting to run on the same thread (the UI thread) at the same time. My investigations into this seem to suggest that the thread switches back and forth between the two sections of code in order to perform them both.

**QUESTION:**

I'm confused about exactly what is going on here. How is it possible to resume on a thread that is already running other code? What forces the thread to switch between the two sections of code that want to run? In general, what happens when you attempt to resume on a thread that is already running some other code?

(I suppose this isn't any different to how my click event runs on the UI thread in the first place, in as much as I know it runs on the UI thread, and I know the UI thread is also doing other stuff, but I've not really thought about it like this before.)

Comment: "async" void button1_Click doesn't make sense as you don't await, so async doesn't do anything. Each TestMethodAsync will run in separate Task, so it will be few copies of TestMethodAsync function. If you have there any variables of the class you are in trouble as they will be accessed from 2 Tasks, you need to protect them.

Comment: Why would you "`Task.Run()`" an async method?

Comment: *My investigations into this seem to suggest that the thread switches back and forth between the two sections of code in order to perform them both.* You are not correct. (2) will be started only after (1) completed.

Comment: @Yuri S I have removed `async` from the event handler to clarify. But I’m only calling `TestMethodAsync` once, so I’m not sure what you mean by ‘each will run in a separate Task’

Comment: @PetSerAl This is not what I’ve seen happen.

Comment: @bornfromanegg If it is (which is unlikely) then it's doing something other than what you're claiming it's doing, like awaiting an asynchronous operation in the code that you've said is synchronous.

Comment: You're a worker. **How do you resume a task that you stopped working on previously if you are currently executing another task**?

Comment: @EricLippert I would need to be able to remember where I left off, so I could pick up from that point. Is this a leading question? :-)

Comment: Yes, you have to remember the *continuation*. Now, supposing you'd remembered the continuation: **how is it that you come to execute the continuation of a previous task if it arrives while you are working on your current task?**  You've put some toast in the toaster; while you're waiting you read the newspaper, pay some bills, oh, the toast popped up.  If you're in the middle of paying a bill, do you stop everything you're doing and go butter the toast, or do you make a mental note that you need to butter the toast in the future?

Comment: @EricLippert They're asking how the UI thread is switching between two *synchronous* methods, executing parts of each in turn.  Not how it's switching between operations composed of asynchronous operations in which various continuations are interviewed.

Comment: Side note but your 'fire and forget' pattern is all wrong.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know. I would not write 'fire and forget' like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the secret that you do not understand: I give you the **Windows Message Loop**

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    while(TRUE)
    {
        bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (bRet <= 0) break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

This is the actual "main" of your application; you just don't see it because it is hidden behind the scenes.

A simpler loop could not be imagined. It gets a message from the queue. If there are no more messages then the program must be done. If there was a message then it runs the standard message translations and dispatches the message, and then keeps on running.

> How is it possible to resume on a thread that is already running other code?

It isn't. "Resuming on a thread that is running other code" is actually *putting a message in the queue*.  That "other code" is being synchronously called by DispatchMessage. When it is done, it returns to the loop, the queue is polled, and the message indicates what code needs to be dispatched next. That then runs synchronously until it returns back to the loop.

> What forces the thread to switch between the two sections of code that want to run?

Nothing. That doesn't happen.

> In general, what happens when you attempt to resume on a thread that is already running some other code?

The message that describes what continuation needs to be run is queued up.

> I suppose this isn't any different to how my click event runs on the UI thread in the first place, in as much as I know it runs on the UI thread, and I know the UI thread is also doing other stuff, but I've not really thought about it like this before.

Start thinking about it.

Click events are exactly the same. Your program is doing something; you click the mouse; the click hander does not interrupt the UI thread and start running new work on it. Rather, the message is queued up, and when your UI thread control returns to the message loop, the click is eventually processed; DispatchMessage causes Button1_OnClick to be invoked via some mechanism in Windows Forms.  That's what WinForms *is*; a mechanism for translating Windows messages into calls to C# methods.

**But you already knew that**.  You know that when an event-driven program does a long-running synchronous operation, that the UI freezes, but that click events are processed eventually.  How did you think that happened?  You must have understood at some level that they were being queued up for processing later, right?

Exercise:  What does `DoEvents` do?

Exercise:  Given what you now know: what could possibly go wrong if you call `DoEvents` in a loop to unblock your UI?

Exercise: How is `await` different from `DoEvents` in a GUI application?

Comment: I wish I could accept both this answer and the one from @Servy. Both of you have said what I needed to hear, which is that my program wasn't doing what I thought it was doing. In order to try to illustrate the fact to myself, I'd inadvertently put some more asynchronous code in there. It's fantastic to be told you're wrong when what you think is happening doesn't make sense. Thank you so much for your explanations.

Comment: In answer to your questions, I haven't used DoEvents since VB6, and from what I remember, it was a potential minefield back then. As I remember, it tells the message queue to process all outstanding events (which can end up calling the method you're currently in). How is it different from `await`? I suppose I would say that `DoEvents` effectively blocks execution of your current method until `DoEvents` is complete, whereas `await` yields control to the UI thread until your method is ready to continue (at which point the continuation is queued).

Comment: @bornfromanegg: You're welcome. `DoEvents` simply *pulls another message off the queue and processes it*, but that happens not in the *main* message loop, but wherever `DoEvents` is called. So for example, suppose you're in a click handler, and you call DoEvents. It is 100% possible for that to *recursively call the click handler*, and odds are pretty good that your click handler was not designed for recursion. You can get into similar cleft sticks with `await`, but the sequence of calls is different.

Comment: @bornfromanegg: Your characterization of `DoEvents` as being essentially a *synchronous event pump* is correct, and that is precisely what makes it dangerous. It means that there are now *multiple* places in the code that are pumping the queue, which can make code very hard to reason about.

Comment: The potentially recursive aspect of DoEvents is I think the main reason I think I'd be wary of it. Even in VB6 days, we were warned to be careful with it, but the alternatives were so much harder back then. Like I say, I've not used it since then, and I'm honestly quite surprised to hear it's still around!

Answer (score 4):

> How is it possible to resume on a thread that is already running other code?

It needs to be specifically designed to support it.  There needs to be some framework in place that allows the thread to take in work and to then execute that work at some later point in time.

This is how your UI thread works.  It has a queue, and whenever you schedule work to be done in the UI thread you add an item to the end of the queue.  The UI thread then takes the first item from the queue, executes it, and then when it's done, goes on to the next item, and so on, until you end your application.

> What forces the thread to switch between the two sections of code that want to run?

Nothing, because it doesn't do that.  It runs one, then when it finishes, it runs the other.

> In general, what happens when you attempt to resume on a thread that is already running some other code?

Either someone wrote some custom code to specifically do just that, in which case, it does whatever that code specifically told it to do, or else you can't.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. As both you and @PetSerAl pointed out in the comments under the main question, my code was not doing what I thought it was doing, and in fact it was precisely what you said - there was some async code in the code I had thought was synchronous.