# Increment number with Delay (C#)

Tags: c#, uwp

i have a button when i click on it it increases the number in a text block by one.
But i want to show increment with few millisecond wait.

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Name="DisplayTextBlock" FontSize="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

<Button Name="CountingButton" Height="80" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="CountingButton_Click"/>
```

**C#**

```
int i = 0;

private void CountingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    do
    {
        i++;

        DisplayTextBlock.Text = i.ToString();
    }
    while(//something is on)
}
```

so how can i add wait...

Comment: A 'few milliseconds' isn't detectable to the user. Delay many milliseconds and you block the UI for too long. You probably need to learn about Timers.

Comment: there are many similar answer so i have too accept so very first answer i am marking as answer iam checking

Comment: @ArpitJain It is recommended to wait for some time (24 hours?) before accepting an answer. Especially if none of the existing ones exactly is what you need.

Comment: i am adding delay because that event can check that thing is on or off because that thing is changing frequently so it can wait to check. it is wrong or right ? or i should use any other method

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47271341) applies to WPF and your situation too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as you want to update it indefinitely, I've changed my previous answer to use a timer. My solution is toggling the enabled state with a subsequent click of the button for illustration purposes. Consider the following:

```
DispatcherTimer _timer;

private int i = 0;

public bool SomethingIsOn { get; private set; } = true;

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_timer == null && SomethingIsOn)
    {
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer()
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)
        };
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
    }
  else if(_timer != null)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        ((Button)sender).IsEnabled = false;
    }
}

private void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    if (SomethingIsOn)
    {
        i++;
        DisplayTextBlock.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

In your proper solution, you might want to disable the button when it is clicked the first time to avoid having the user click it multiple times.

**Update**
I'm now using the DispatcherTimer which is available in UWP and easier to work with.

Comment: @Fabulous Heads up: OP changed code snippet in question. I think it changes the game.

Comment: @Fildor thanks for the heads up. I'll have a look and change my code accordingly

Comment: will it full fill my this condition "i am adding delay because that event can check that thing is on or off because that thing is changing frequently so it can wait to check. it is wrong or right ? or i should use any other method"

Comment: In this case, the timer will wait the allotted amount of time, 300 milliseconds in my code, and then run the elapsed event. That event does check if something is on so it will check each time around.

Comment: You'll have to change the `if(SomethingIsOn)` bit to make your check. Mine is calling a property that is set to true and isn't changing. Once you've made that change, the timer event will check before setting the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158979/discussion-between-arpit-jain-and-fabulous).

Comment: @Fabulous I deleted my answer in favor of yours. I couldn't provide another example (out of time).

Answer (score 5):

Add the `async` keyword to the method declaration. And add `Task.Delay`.

```
private async void CountingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    i++;
    await Task.Delay(200);
    DisplayTestBlock.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Pac0 for event handlers you can use `async void` since you cannot change the return value or signature of the event handler.

Comment: it shows an error delay does not exist in namespace system.threding.task

Comment: @ArpitJain, `Task` is class inside `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace, Add it in as the first line in your current file. `using System.Threading.Tasks`, or you can click on the error in the text editor, and press `CTRL+.`

Comment: okay, visual studios was some problem adding namespace now this namespace is added

Comment: @OrelEraki Heads up: OP changed code snippet in question. I think it changes the game.

Comment: @ArpitJain, I also confused, i wrote you `System.Threading.Task` instread of `System.Threading.Tasks` with `s` at the end.

Comment: @Fildor, now it's different question. he didn't say it increases until X (forever, times or seconds). He can later morph the question again. Is there any end ?

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is sleep:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(x);
```

If not Delay would work too:

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Delay(x);
```

Comment: Though this `Thread.Sleep(x)` will do the job, that will actually block the thread while sleeping, so it's better to use `await Tasks.Delay(x)`