# Predefined events in WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi

I have a question how predifined events are working like button click,form load etc.Does the compiler send message to form class or button class when we click the button or form loading?I searched number of sites regarding this question but I didn't get answer.That sites show only how to create event and how to subscribe it.I am wondering to know that.If anyone know this please share me.

Comment: Events happen at run-time, when the compiler is not around anymore.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47271341/60761) is about what happens inside `Application.Run()`. It may be a little over your head now but it has all the relevant words to search for.

Answer (score 1):

Those events are triggered when a certain Windows Message has been sent by Windows.  The WndPrc method captures this message, and will this will eventually cause that the appropriate event is launched by the WinForms implementation.  (Which is in fact a wrapper around the Windows API)

More information can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775494(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941(v=vs.85).aspx#messages_to_buttons)

You can also check out the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs) of the WinForms Button class for instance, and see when the `OnClick` event is raised.  In the WndProc method you can see that the OnClick event is raised if a certain windows message (WM_COMMAND) with a certain value for the high order bit in `WParam` is set.